# does more widgets in main page causes bad loading on wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, widget, loading

I'm using a specific widget that coded myself and use this widget on main page almost 18 times for displaying different category posts. does it cause bad loading in main page or not?! if I use normal coding instead of the widget is that better or not different?! You can check my website loading http://akhbartop.com/ In my system and some friends loading of the main page is not good. I want to know more widget in main page related to loading or not?! What do you suggest instead using a widget?!
this is my codes in widget

```
   <?php
// Creating the widget
class wpb_box extends WP_Widget {
function __construct() {
parent::__construct(
// Base ID of your widget
'wpb_box',
// Widget name will appear in UI
__('ابزارک اختصاصی باکس مطالب خبرخوان', 'bigtheme'),
// Widget description
array( 'description' => __( 'ابزارک نمایش باکس مطالب از سایت های مختلف توسط آدرس خوراک یا فید سایت', 'bigtheme' ), )
);
add_action('save_post', array( $this, 'delete_query_caches') );
}
// Creating widget front-end
// This is where the action happens
/**
     * Delete transients
     */
    function delete_query_caches( $post_id ){
        if( !isset( $_POST['post_type'] ) || $_POST['post_type'] !== 'post' ) return;

        $categories = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, 'category' );

        if( $categories && ! is_WP_Error( $categories ) ) {
            foreach( $categories as $cat ) {
                delete_transient('post'.$cat->term_id.'_query');
            }
        }
    }
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        $name = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['name'] );
        $category = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['category'] );
        $id = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['id'] );
$link = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['link'] );
        $display = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['display'] );
        $color = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['color'] );
// This is where you run the code and display the output
?>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 padding5">
                <div class="article">
                        <div class="title">     
                            <h3><a href="<?php echo $link ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $name ?></a></h3>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                    </div>

                               <?php
if ( false === ( $slider = get_transient( 'post'.$id.'_query' ) ) ) {

     $slider = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_status' =>'publish',
            'post_type' =>'post',
            'cat' =>''.$id.'',
            'posts_per_page' =>'9'      
        ));

    // Make a new query cache for 1 week
    set_transient( 'post'.$id.'_query', $slider, 168 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS );

}
if( !$slider->have_posts() ) return; ?>
<ul>
<?php while( $slider->have_posts() ) : $slider->the_post(); ?>
<li>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<div style="display:<?php echo $display;?>" class="tooltiptext hidden-xs"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
</li>
<?php endwhile; $slider->rewind_posts(); ?>
</ul>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<div class="list"><a href="<?php echo $link ?>" target="_blank">مشاهده آرشیو کامل</a><a href="<?php echo $link ?>/feed" target="_blank"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/rss.png" width="18" height="18" alt="خوراک سایت" ></a></div>
            </div>
                </div>
<?php
echo $args['after_widget'];
}
public function form( $instance ) {
        $name   = ( isset( $instance[ 'name' ] ) ) ? $instance[ 'name' ] : '';
        $category   = ( isset( $instance[ 'category' ] ) ) ? $instance[ 'category' ] : '';
$link   = ( isset( $instance[ 'link' ] ) ) ? $instance[ 'link' ] : '';
        $color  = ( isset( $instance[ 'color' ] ) ) ? $instance[ 'color' ] : '';
        $id     = ( isset( $instance[ 'id' ] ) ) ? $instance[ 'id' ] : '';
        $display    = ( isset( $instance[ 'display' ] ) ) ? $instance[ 'display' ] : '';
?>
            <p>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'color' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'رنگ باکس مطالب:' ); ?></label>
                <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'color' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'color' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $color ); ?>" placeholder="مثال : #CCC , #dd3333 , black , blue" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'name' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'عنوان باکس:' ); ?></label>
                <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'name' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'name' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $name ); ?>" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'id' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'آی دی دسته بندی' ); ?></label>
                <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'id' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'id' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $id ); ?>" />
            </p>
            <select id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('category'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('category'); ?>" class="widefat" style="width:100%;">
            <?php foreach(get_terms('category','parent=0&hide_empty=0') as $term) { ?>
            <option <?php selected( $instance['category'], $term->term_id ); ?> value="<?php echo $term->term_id; ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>      
        </select>
<p>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'link' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'لینک آرشیو' ); ?></label>
                <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'link' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'link' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $link ); ?>" />
            </p>

            <p>
                <label><?php _e( 'نمایش توضیحات مطالب' ); ?></label>
                <select class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'display' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'display' ); ?>">
                    <option <?php selected( $instance['display'], 'block'); ?> value="block">بله</option> 
                    <option <?php selected( $instance['display'], 'none'); ?> value="none">خیر</option> 
                </select>
            </p>

<?php
}
// Updating widget replacing old instances with new
public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = array();
        $instance['name'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['name'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['name'] ) : '';
        $instance['category'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['category'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['category'] ) : '';
$instance['link'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['link'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['link'] ) : '';
        $instance['link2'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['link2'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['link2'] ) : '';
        $instance['id'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['id'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['id'] ) : '';
        $instance['link3'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['link3'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['link3'] ) : '';
        $instance['link4'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['link4'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['link4'] ) : '';
        $instance['link5'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['link5'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['link5'] ) : '';
        $instance['color'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['color'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['color'] ) : '';
        $instance['display'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['display'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['display'] ) : '';
        $instance['source'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['source'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['source'] ) : '';
        $instance['time'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['time'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['time'] ) : '';
        return $instance;
    }
} // Class wpb_box ends here
// Register and load the widget
function wpb_box() {
register_widget( 'wpb_box' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'wpb_box' );
?>
```

i did some changes and put transient api codes in widget but still has problem with widget updates!!!when posts publish widgets won't update!!

Comment: custom code is always the better comparison to redimate stuf .

Comment: so you suggest write custom code instead of widget.in this case i just can write the exactly code from the widget to main page.it is better?!

Comment: There are not necessary to use widgets you can create you can create the custom template for your home page and then create the hook of code which one you using as a widget .yes I suggest you use code instead of widget, widget is for the user's who's don't know much about code. if you know the code well then go ahead.

Comment: ok thank you.yes i know codes but i used widget because of ease :)
so widget effect on web loading right?!

Comment: correct you can use one or two BTW if more then it will make your website heavy and load speed will decrease.

Comment: Not correct. See my answer. Widgets are not slow by design, using them in the wrong way may very well be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using too many queries, caching the queries might be helpful.
Let's say your custom widget looks like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * My widget class
*/
class dw_myWidget extends WP_Widget {

    function __construct() {
        // Instantiate the parent object
        parent::__construct( false, __('My widget') );

    }

    function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        $title    = apply_filters( 'title', $instance['title'] );
        $link1    = apply_filters( 'category', $instance['category'] ); // category id


        $portfolio = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_status' =>'publish',
            'post_type' =>'post',
            'cat' =>''.$link1.'',
            'posts_per_page' =>'9'      
        ));


        // And the rest of the code
    }

    function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        // update stuff
    }

    function form( $instance ) {
        // widget form stuff
    }
}

function dw_MyWidget_register() {
    register_widget( 'dw_myWidget' );
}

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'dw_MyWidget_register' );
```

We cache the query using Wordpress's transient key, but since we don't know how many widgets will be out there we must include a unique thing in our transient API, like the `$link1` variable which represents the category id:

```
function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    $title    = apply_filters( 'title', $instance['title'] );
    $link1    = apply_filters( 'category', $instance['category'] ); // category id


    if ( false === ( $portfolio = get_transient( 'post'.$link1.'_query' ) ) ) {
        $portfolio = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_status' =>'publish',
            'post_type' =>'post',
            'cat' =>''.$link1.'',
            'posts_per_page' =>'9'      
        ));

        set_transient( 'post'.$link1.'_query', $portfolio, 168 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
    }

    // And the rest of the code
}
```

That's not all, we need to delete the transient when a new post is created, so we register a hook to `save_post` action, in the constructor

```
function __construct() {
    // Instantiate the parent object
    parent::__construct( false, __('My widget') );

    add_action('save_post', array( $this, 'delete_query_caches') );
}

/**
 * Delete transients
 */
function delete_query_caches( $post_id ){
    if( !isset( $_POST['post_type'] ) || $_POST['post_type'] !== 'post' ) return;

    $categories = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, 'category' );

    if( $categories && ! is_WP_Error( $categories ) ) {
        foreach( $categories as $cat ) {
            delete_transient('post'.$cat->term_id.'_query');
        }
    }
}
```

So the final code looks something like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * My widget class
*/
class dw_myWidget extends WP_Widget {

    function __construct() {
        // Instantiate the parent object
        parent::__construct( false, __('My widget') );

        add_action('save_post', array( $this, 'delete_query_caches') );
    }

    /**
     * Delete transients
     */
    function delete_query_caches( $post_id ){
        if( !isset( $_POST['post_type'] ) || $_POST['post_type'] !== 'post' ) return;

        $categories = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, 'category' );

        if( $categories && ! is_WP_Error( $categories ) ) {
            foreach( $categories as $cat ) {
                delete_transient('post'.$cat->term_id.'_query');
            }
        }
    }

    function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        $title    = apply_filters( 'title', $instance['title'] );
        $link1    = apply_filters( 'category', $instance['category'] ); // category id


        if ( false === ( $portfolio = get_transient( 'post'.$link1.'_query' ) ) ) {
            $portfolio = new WP_Query(array(
                'post_status' =>'publish',
                'post_type' =>'post',
                'cat' =>''.$link1.'',
                'posts_per_page' =>'9'      
            ));

            set_transient( 'post'.$link1.'_query', $portfolio, 168 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
        }

        // And the rest of the code
    }

    function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        // update stuff
    }

    function form( $instance ) {
        // widget form stuff
    }
}

function dw_MyWidget_register() {
    register_widget( 'dw_myWidget' );
}

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'dw_MyWidget_register' );
```

Hope it'll help.

Comment: there is a problem in delete cache.when new posts publish widgets won't update!!!!

Answer (score 1):

From the code point of view, it does not matter where the code resides. Your code is executed in the same way whether it's a widget or a template part, or a plugin function hooked to some action.

What does matter is what the code is actually doing and how (and again, it does not matter where the code is).

In your case, I suppose, the widget is getting some RSS feeds, thus making http requests to external resources. These requests are slow, the results must be cached to avoid repeating the requests on every page load. You can have different expiration time (even 30 seconds difference) for each instance of the widget to try to prevent them all updating at the same time. Or even better, you should update them in the background, never making a front-end visitor to fetch those feeds.

[Transients API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) is what you should use to make it fast.

Comment: thank you for your answer.no widgets don't fetch feeds just display posts from specific category.fetching post do by wp_automatic plugin.posts are save in our database and display in website from my database not external database.but for caching main page i need help to solve this problem :)

Comment: i'm using wp-rocket plugin for cache website.do you think get cache on 24 hours or unlimited time (never cache until need this)?!!how can i use Transients API on main page?!

Comment: i edited main question and you can see my codes that i'm using in widget for every specific category posts